# TCP Client connection from a Docker Container

Tags: docker, networking, tcp, docker-desktop

I am running a Docker Container on Mac OSX (High Sierra) via the Docker Desktop.

My container is running CentOS 7.5.1804 along with a bunch of my custom code. The code has a GUI so I use X11 forwarding to manage that, and it mounts to a specific directory on the host machine (all of that is working great).

My docker run command is currently:

```
docker run -d -t -e DISPLAY=host.docker.internal:0 --mount type=bind,source=$HOME/some_dir,target=/some_dir image_name
```

After the Container is up an running, if I log into it, I can create a TCP Server (via Ruby's TCPServer class) no problem, and then connect to that server with a TCP Client (via Ruby's TCPSocket class) on the Host. However, if I create a TCP Server on the Host, a TCP Client in the Container fails to connect (almost like the network traffic is 1 way).

Ultimately, I have a source of data on a machine the Host can talk to, that creates a TCP Server to distribute the data. I wanted to have the Container start up a TCP Client, and then connect to that server (likely via an SSH-Tunnel on my Host), but I can't get that to work.

I have tried a few combinations of the following in the docker run command, but nothing seems to work, so I think there is something fundamental about Docker networks that I am missing.

```
--network host
--add-host="localhost:<my_ip>"
-p 5555:5555
```

Thanks in advance for any help/suggestions!

---

I was able to figure out how to do to this.

The key is that on a Mac, there is a changing IP address that you need to connect to to reach the Host.

Docker 17.06 and onwards support hostname 'docker.for.mac.localhost' which will resolve to the correct IP address.

That means that in my container, my TCP Client would look like:

```
TCPSocket(docker.for.mac.localhost, 5555)
```

And the Host TCP Server would look like:

```
TCPServer(5555)
```

And that worked, both sides successfully saw the connection.

Comment: TCP does not have clients or servers, it has peers. The client/server concept is an application concept, and TCP knows nothing about clients or servers. You can also run into problems if you use NAPT, which can cause a TCP connection to be able to be initiated only from one side, but not the other side.

Comment: @RonMaupin To handle the TCP communication I'm using Ruby's TCPServer (as what I was describing as the server) and TCPSocket (as what I was describing as the client).